# How to read tty until EOT or some other character in bash?

Tags: tty, cat

I'm trying to send and receive some string data from/to microcontroller and use bash on linux machine.

At this moment code on my microcontroller looks like this:

```
void UART_help_cmd_handler() 
{
    printf("Available commands:\n");
    printf("search - starts search and returns device addresses\n");
    printf("help - prints this help\n");

    // these characters can't stop cat
    EUSART2_Write(0);
    EUSART2_Write(0x03);
    EUSART2_Write(0x04);
}
```

And this is linux side:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -ne '\x02help\x03' > /dev/ttyUSB0; cat /dev/ttyUSB0;
```

I also tried:

```
echo -ne '\x02help\x03' > /dev/ttyUSB0; stdbuf -i 0 -o 0 cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

The problem is that I can't make `cat` stop from microcontroller side.

I have tried to send `-1` character from microcontroller, I have tried with 0x03.

Comment: Bash and cat are NOT the right tools to do serial port programming, and those `VINTR`/`^C`, `VEOF`/`^D` characters don't work the way you seem to assume: please take some time to read the [`termios(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) manpage. For a quick-n-dirty fix, you can try setting the tty in canonical mode (`stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 icanon`) and sending the `^D` twice (repeat the `EUSART2_Write(0x04);`)

Comment: And FYI: `stdbuf(1)` only has any effect on programs which use stdio, and `cat` is not one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. To get desired behavior (command->response between uart and bash) I wrote something like this:

**Microcontroller side:**

```
void UART_help_cmd_handler() 
{
    // this delay prevents buffer overflow on linux side if bash is too slow
    // see "However" section below
    __delay_ms(100); 


    printf("Available commands:\n");
    printf("search - starts search and returns device addresses\n");
    printf("help - prints this help\n");

    // second newline to mark end of transmission
    // that cat command can read
    printf("\n");  
}
```

** Bash side **

```
#!/bin/bash

# send-command-read-response.sh

# send command 
# (in my case microcontroller needs 0x02 byte to find start of command 
$ and 0x03 byte for end of command

echo -ne "\x02${1}\x03" > /dev/ttyUSB0;

# read lines one by one until "" (empty line)
file="/dev/ttyUSB0"
terminator=""
while IFS= read line
do
    if [ "$line" = "$terminator" ]; then
        break
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done <"$file"
```

**However:**

- when microcontroller response is fast - sometimes bash is not able to run "read" command quick enough to drain hardware uart buffer before it was full, so I had to add dirty delay
- maybe "fast microcontroller response" problem could be solved if I could use hardware flow control, but I'm not sure
- I can't find the way to handle timeout somehow in bash (if microcontroller is not responding for some reasons).

**Finally**

- as @mosvy wrote in comment under my question - bash is not the right tool for serial communication
- I think it is possible to handle two way serial communication in bash if hardware flow control is possible. Timeout can set by `stty`, but I think that there is too much effort to archieve this.
- I wrote simple application, it can handle timeout and other error.

I tried to avoid C/C++ application because I need to replace bash script in some large web application that accepts bash scripts, but extra binary files are "not welcome".